# Download a file(attachment) on href sending Authorization Header

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-web-api

In my web api app(.net webapi) y need to pass the authorization header when a download link is clicked. 
Normally, when you use a href link this not pass the authorization header and then, the api authorization denegate the download(api request with axios).

How to achieve this and add this authorization header when href is clicked with a React-redux front?

or another way to aproach this...

Comment: As long as the link points to the same server, the Authorization header is included in the request

Answer (score 0):

href link won't be possible.

You will need to make a xhr request. I'm not familiar with react well, but in vue.js projects I use axios library to perform such requests

https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

Comment: I'm using axios but I'm not familiar too with xhr request.

Comment: Evry request with axios is XHR request. Be fore you do your axios request you can the header you need.
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = AUTH_TOKEN;

Comment: I'm actually doing this, but the href link does not include the authorization.